# Modify Frame Scrolling From Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a frame that has scrolling disabled, I need to enable this through javascript. I can get the frame in the DOM using

frame = top.frmMain.id;

I'm struggling to work out how to then turn on scrolling. Its probably something really simple that I am missing. I guess I need to remove the scrolling=no attribute, any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want overflow:scroll (both scroll bars) or overflow:auto (only the needed scroll bar and only if needed - preferred by me)

Comment: I need overflow:auto. It's currently just set on the frame to scrolling=no

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.setAttribute('scrolling', 'auto');
```

or

```
frame.setAttribute('scrolling', 'yes');
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I don't know if the `scrolling` attribute overrides the `style` attribute or the other way around, but the style can be set using `frame.style.overflow = 'auto';`

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a fairly old thread, but still..

In most browsers

```
frame.setAttribute('scrolling', 'yes');
```

does the trick. However, IE seems do disregard changes happening on this property, and rather use the frames documents body attribute'scroll'.
So, for a more complete solution:

```
frame.setAttribute('scrolling', 'yes');
frame.contentDocument && frame.contentDocument.body && (frame.contentDocument.body.scroll = 'yes');
```

I'm using && to check for the existence of the properties, as .contentDocument may not exist in other browsers, and .body may not exist if the frame is not yet loaded.